# I am still logged in even if i click logout and redirected to login page

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a member system but i have a problem with logging out.

When i press the log-out button i am redirected to the log-in page but when i visit the user update page directly from the browser i am still logged in even though i logged out.

If i go to the log-in page and log-in again and visit the user update page i can see the previous users data and not mine.

You can go here: http://dailypaychecknetwork.com/account/createnewuser.php and create an account test for your self please.

Below is my log-out and member-config.php script any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

**member-config.php script:**

```
//Require DB connection
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/connect.php";

//Pages to require
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/languages/en.php";
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/class.newuser.php";
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/class.user.php";
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/funcs.php";

session_save_path("/home/users/web/b1951/moo.dailypaychecknetwork/cgi-bin/tmp");

session_start();

//Global User Object Var
//loggedInUser can be used globally if constructed
if(isset($_SESSION["userCakeUser"]) && is_object($_SESSION["userCakeUser"]))
{
    $loggedInUser = $_SESSION["userCakeUser"];
}
```

**Log-out script:**

```
require_once("models/member-config.php");

//Log the user out
/*if(isUserLoggedIn())
{
    $loggedInUser->userLogOut();
}*/

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();

header("Location: login.php");
die();
```

**Update script:**

```
require_once("models/member-config.php");

//Prevent the user visiting the page if he is not logged in
if($loggedInUser == NULL){ header("Location: login.php"); die(); }

if(isset($_POST['dpnupdate']))
{
    $errors = array();
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $fname = $_POST["fname"];
    $lname = $_POST["lname"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $znzsid = $_POST["znzsid"];
    $znzdid = $_POST["znzdid"];
    $enid = $_POST["enid"];
    $znztl = $_POST["znztl"];

    //Update a users email
    if($email != $loggedInUser->email)
    {
        if(trim($email) == "")
        {
            $errors[] = lang("EMAIL_EMPTY");
        }
        else if(!isValidEmail($email))
        {
            $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_INVALID_EMAIL");
        }
        else if(emailExists($email))
        {
            $errors[] = lang("EMAIL_EXIST", array($email)); 
        }

        //End data validation
        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {
            $loggedInUser->updateEmail($email);
            $successes[] = lang("ACCOUNT_EMAIL_UPDATED");
        }
    }

    //Update a users first name 
    if($fname != $loggedInUser->fname)
    {
        if(trim($fname) == "")
        {
            $errors[] = lang("FIRST_NAME_EMPTY");
        }       
        //End data validation
        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {
            $loggedInUser->updateFirstname($fname);
            $successes[] = lang("ACCOUNT_FIRST_NAME_UPDATED");
        }
    }

    //Update a users last name  
    if($lname != $loggedInUser->lname)
    {
        if(trim($lname) == "")
        {
            $errors[] = lang("LAST_NAME_EMPTY");
        }       
        //End data validation
        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {
            $loggedInUser->updateLastname($fname);
            $successes[] = lang("ACCOUNT_LAST_NAME_UPDATED");
        }
    }

    //Update a users phone number   
    if($phone != $loggedInUser->phone)
    {
        if(trim($phone) == "")
        {
            $errors[] = lang("PHONE_NUMBER_EMPTY");
        }
        else if(!is_numeric($phone)){
            $errors[] = lang("PHONE_IS_NUMERIC");
        }       
        //End data validation
        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {
            $loggedInUser->updatePhone($phone);
            $successes[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PHONE_NUMBER_UPDATED");
        }
    }

    //Update a users znz single id  
    if($znzsid == 'optional' || $znzsid == $loggedInUser->znzsingle)
    {} else{
        if(trim($znzsid) == "")
        {
            $errors[] = lang("ZNZ_SINGLE_EMPTY");
        }
        else if(!is_numeric($znzsid)){
            $errors[] = lang("ZNZ_SINGLE_IS_NUMERIC");
        }
        //End data validation
        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {
            $loggedInUser->updateZnzsingle($znzsid);
            $successes[] = lang("ACCOUNT_ZNZ_SINGLE_UPDATED");
        }
    }

    //Update a users znz double id  
    if($znzdid == 'optional' || $znzdid == $loggedInUser->znzdouble)
    {} else{
        if(trim($znzdid) == "")
        {
            $errors[] = lang("ZNZ_DOUBLE_EMPTY");
        }
        else if(!is_numeric($znzdid)){
            $errors[] = lang("ZNZ_DOUBLE_IS_NUMERIC");
        }
        //End data validation
        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {
            $loggedInUser->updateZnzdouble($znzdid);
            $successes[] = lang("ACCOUNT_ZNZ_DOUBLE_UPDATED");
        }
    }

    //Update a users empoer network id
    if($enid != $loggedInUser->empowerid)
    {
        if(trim($enid) == "")
        {
            $errors[] = lang("EMPOWER_NETWORK_EMPTY");
        }   
        //End data validation
        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {
            $loggedInUser->updateEmpowerid($enid);
            $successes[] = lang("ACCOUNT_EMPOWER_NETWORK_UPDATED");
        }
    }

    //Update a users znzadteam link
    if($znztl != $loggedInUser->znzadteamlink)
    {
        if(trim($znztl) == "")
        {
            $errors[] = lang("ZNZADTEAM_LINK_EMPTY");
        }       
        //End data validation
        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {
            $loggedInUser->updateZnzadteam($znztl);
            $successes[] = lang("ACCOUNT_ZNZADTEAM_LINK_UPDATED");
        }
    }

    if(count($errors) == 0 AND count($successes) == 0){
        $errors[] = lang("NOTHING_TO_UPDATE");
    }
}

//Update password
if(isset($_POST['dpnupdatepass']))
{

    $errors = array();
    $successes = array();
    $password = $_POST["oldpass"];
    $password_new = $_POST["newpass"];  

    //Confirm the hashes match before updating a users password
    $entered_pass = md5($password);

    if (trim($password) == ""){
        $errors[] = lang("PASSWORD_EMPTY");
    }
    else if($entered_pass != $loggedInUser->pass)
    {
        //No match
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_INVALID");
    }   

    if ($password_new != "")
    {
        if(trim($password_new) == "")
        {
            $errors[] = lang("PASSWORD_EMPTY");
        }

        //End data validation
        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {
            //Also prevent updating if someone attempts to update with the same password
            $entered_pass_new = md5($password_new);

            if($entered_pass_new == $loggedInUser->pass)
            {
                //Don't update, this fool is trying to update with the same password Â¬Â¬
                $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_NOTHING_TO_UPDATE");
            }
            else
            {
                //This function will create the new hash and update the pass property.
                $loggedInUser->updatePassword($password_new);
                $successes[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_UPDATED");
            }
        }
    }
    if(count($errors) == 0 AND count($successes) == 0){
        $errors[] = lang("NOTHING_TO_UPDATE");
    }

}

require_once("../includes/header.php");
echo "
<div class='main-content-wrap'>
    <div class='back'> <a href='http://dailypaychecknetwork.com/account/account.php'>< BACK OFFICE</a></div>
    <h2 class='center-title'>Update your info</h2>
    <div class='main-content'>

        <div id='main'>";

        echo resultBlock($errors,$successes);

        echo "  
        <div id='regbox'>
                <form name='newUser' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
                    <table cellpadding='3px' class='mtext'>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class='tdSubHeader'><label>Email</label></td>
                                <td class='tdContent'><input type='text' name='email' value='".$loggedInUser->email."' size='25'/></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class='tdSubHeader'><label>First Name</label></td>
                                <td class='tdContent'><input type='text' name='fname' value='".$loggedInUser->fname."' size='25'/></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class='tdSubHeader'><label>Last Name</label></td>
                                <td class='tdContent'><input type='text' name='lname' value='".$loggedInUser->lname."' size='25'/></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class='tdSubHeader'><label>Phone</label></td>
                                <td class='tdContent'><input type='text' name='phone' value='".$loggedInUser->phonee."' size='25'/></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class='tdSubHeader'><label>ZNZ Single ID #</label></td>
                                <td class='tdContent'><input type='text' name='znzsid' value='".(($loggedInUser->znzsingle == 1313434) ? 'optional' : $loggedInUser->znzsingle)."' size='40'/></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class='tdSubHeader'><label>ZNZ Double ID #</label></td>
                                <td class='tdContent'><input type='text' name='znzdid' value='".(($loggedInUser->znzdouble == 1314445) ? 'optional' : $loggedInUser->znzdouble)."' size='40'/></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class='tdSubHeader'><label>Empower Network ID</label></td>
                                <td class='tdContent'><input type='text' name='enid' value='".$loggedInUser->empowerid."' size='40'/></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class='tdSubHeader'><label>ZNZADTEAM LINK</label></td>
                                <td class='tdContent'><input type='text' name='znztl' value='".$loggedInUser->znzadteamlink."' size='40'/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                        <br>
                        <div style='float:left;'><input type='submit' name='dpnupdate' value='Save Changes'></div>                  
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='sidebar-update'>
        <div class='third-party-autoresponder'>
            <h2>3rd Party Autoresponder</h2>

        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class='change-password'>
            <h2>Change Password</h2>
            <form name='newUser' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
                    <table cellpadding='3px' class='mtext'>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class='tdSubHeader'><label>Old Password</label></td>
                                <td class='tdContent'><input type='password' name='oldpass' size='25'/></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class='tdSubHeader'><label>New Password</label></td>
                                <td class='tdContent'><input type='password' name='newpass' size='25'/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                        <br>
                        <div><input type='submit' name='dpnupdatepass' value='Save New Password'></div>                 
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
";
require_once("../includes/footer.php");
```

Comment: Calling `session_regenerate_id()` on each page load surely is not a good thing. You can omit that function entirely.

Comment: Did that but still having the problem

Comment: in the logout script, change the `include` to `require_once` like in the other scripts. that way you'll get an error, if it fails. (this may be an issue if the login- and the logout-scripts are in different folders)

Comment: Any messages logged in your web-server (apache) error log?

Comment: I changed it and both scripts are in the same folder but i still have the problem.

Comment: Any other suggestions

Comment: seems browser do not delete session cookie. cookie params must be exactly the same, not only the name. So check cookie header when you put it to the browser and when you delete it. f12 tool in browser helps.

Comment: I don't quite understand could you explain further thank you.